# Alternative to Checklist.com that isn't buggy and slow (reusable checklists)

Tags: android, productivity, todo

Checklist.com does what I need:

- Multiple checklists for different occasions (I have ones for "Camping", "Hiking", "Going to a wedding", etc.)
- Nested lists ("Clothing to pack", for instance, with socks, shirts, etc. under it)
- Reusable lists (I can uncheck the entire list in one click, then check each thing again)
- Checked items can be hidden at the bottom, leaving only un-checked items visible, if you sort by Status
- Phone app that syncs with web app, so I can check things off on my phone

However, it is slow (checking an item can take seconds to process), and it is buggy (nested lists are not handled correctly depending on the sort, mangling the list permanently), and if you check off every item in a sub-list it automatically checks the parent item, which is not what I would like.

Any alternatives that provide the same functionality without the flaws?

It would be even better if I could categorize list items, like things that appear in both the "Camping" and "Visiting Family" lists, so I could see the union of each list in one place.

I am looking for a "pre-flight checklist", *not* a To Do list or a habit tracker.

Comment: Hi. May be also add the alternatives you have already looked at.  Some options to look at are: https://vikunja.io/ and https://todoist.com/ . You will have to confirm if they meet your requirements.

Comment: @ZZ I'm looking through https://vikunja.cloud/features and I don't see anything about checklists.  Are you confusing checklists with todo lists?

Comment: Andddd it failed me again. Somehow "sleeping bag" got checked off despite me not checking it, and now I have to buy one...

Comment: I tried Notion's checklists but they're still "To Do list"-based, meaning you have to manually move everything back into the "To-do" state.

Answer (score -1):

Trello is the finest substitute, and it's free. Some of it's features include:

- Checklists
- Kanban Board
- Search by tags
- Content Filtering
- Support for @mentions
- Project Management
- List management
- Export to iCalendar
- Drag 'n' Drop
- Calendar integration
- Trello integration
- Multiple Account support
- Scheduling
- Planning Board
- Support for Keyboard Shortcuts
- IFTTT integration
- Real-time collaboration
- Slack integration
- Preview links
- Periodic reminders

Also, Todoist, Asana, WorkFlowy, and Basecamp are additional fantastic tools like Checklist.com.

Comment: Todoist is not a good solution, it doesn't have any way to reuse lists. I haven't tried the others, but if you're suggesting Todoist, then I'm not optimistic about them, either.

Comment: Trello supports checklists, but only flat lists inside of "cards", which doesn't really seem like the same thing.  No nested lists, etc. https://www.technipages.com/trello-add-checklists